# SQLite3::SQLException: near "&": syntax error: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE (menu_display=true && is_published=true)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

How to get rid of this exception?!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: One gets SQLite errors from SQLite, not MySQL, so I adjusted the tags.

Comment: did you write that SQL sentence ?, replace `&&` for `AND`.

Comment: yes, it worked on Mysql, but not on sqlite3, so I am thinking about how to adjust the grammer, change && to AND doesn't work, but it will pass if I just do @pageNav=Page.all

Answer (score 2):

Use the power of Rails and use

```
Page.where(:menu_display => true, :is_published => true)...
```